# The Complement of a Finite Graph Contains a Component that is Infinite

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, computer-science

I am attempting to understand this statement made in "Adjacency in digital pictures" by Azriel Rosenfeld, a paper I am reading on digital pictures and their topology. (You can find the paper here. http://shorturl.at/djvH9)

Specifically, he makes the following statement:

> "Let $\overline{S}$ be the complement of $S$. If $S$ is finite, all points of $\overline{S}$ that are sufficiently far from the origin are evidently connected in $\overline{S}$. It follows that exactly one component of $\overline{S}$ is infinite; we call this component the background of $\overline{S}$."

I am seeking to understand why "it follows that exactly one component of $\overline{S}$ is infinite." Preferably, I would like to find a proof or paper which would allow me to understand it.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is finite, it is bounded, so it lies within some square $[-n,n]\times[-n,n]$. Any points of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ that are outside that square are connected by a $4$-path with at most two turns. E.g., we can get from $\langle -(n+1),0\rangle$ to $\langle n+1,0\rangle$ by travelling ‘north’ to $\langle -(n+1),n+1\rangle$, ‘east’ to $\langle n+1,n+1\rangle$, and ‘south’ to $\langle n+1,0\rangle$. All of these points are therefore in a single component $C$ of $\overline S$, and that component is clearly infinite. Any other components of $\overline S$ lie within the square $[-n,n]\times[-n,n]$ and are therefore finite.

Comment: So, in the context of digital pictures (which are clearly finite and contained within such a square) we can consider a "background" of those pictures to be the complement of the set of "points" contained in that picture and that complement would clearly contain some component which is essentially the entire universe (and beyond)?

Comment: @ChrisL: Basically, yes: once we get far enough away from the origin, everything in the complement of the picture is connected. Any finite components of the background have to be in some sense ‘holes’ in the picture.